# Linking Curl to Codeblocks on Windows

Tags: c++, curl, linker, codeblocks, libcurl

I'm using Win7x64 and downloaded [libCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.40.0/dist-w64/curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64.7z)

I added library *.a files from *curl/lib64* to my project in **build options->linker-settings**

Added to **search directories ->compiler** */curl/include* directory. 
I'm trying to compile sample code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl\curl.h>

int main(void)
{
curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
 CURL * myHandle;
 CURLcode result;
 myHandle = curl_easy_init ( ) ;

 curl_easy_setopt(myHandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
 result = curl_easy_perform( myHandle );
 curl_easy_cleanup( myHandle );
 printf("LibCurl rules!\n");

 return 0;
}
```

And I got error :

```
 *||=== Build: Debug in test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| obj\Debug\main.o||In function main':|
 D:\Projects\test\main.cpp|6|undefined reference to
 _imp__curl_global_init'| D:\Projects\test\main.cpp|9|undefined
 reference to _imp__curl_easy_init'|
 D:\Projects\test\main.cpp|11|undefined reference to
 _imp__curl_easy_setopt'| D:\Projects\test\main.cpp|12|undefined
 reference to _imp__curl_easy_perform'|
 D:\Projects\test\main.cpp|13|undefined reference to
 _imp__curl_easy_cleanup'| ||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0
 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|*
```

I have no idea what should I do to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so according to reading another post I tried linking 32x lib and voila it works.

Comment: You should have giving the link or should have written more